# CSV's to Database with Pandas, encoding errors

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am taking a lot of CSV's and sending them to a database.

I am having issues with the UTF encoding format. The price columns, like this

[image]

```
#df = pd.concat([act, vic,nsw,SA,QLD,WA]).reset_index().set_index(['key']).rename_axis('suburb').reset_index().set_index(['state'])


# use pd.concat
df = pd.concat([act, vic,nsw,SA,QLD,WA]).reset_index().set_index(['key']).rename_axis('suburb').reset_index()
# apply lambda to clean the %20
f = lambda s: s.replace('%20', ' ')
df['suburb'] = df['suburb'].apply(f)
#sends data to DB
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://xxx/xxx?charset=utf8', encoding = 'utf-8')


with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df.to_sql('Price_historic', conn, if_exists='replace',index=True)
```

How do i ensure I don't get the error below?

[image]

Comment: "Incorrect string value" - could it be dtype mismatch between object and numeric? I see your price column has strings and numbers

Comment: Definitely - Yet I would think it wouldn't set a type for the values>?

Comment: I would think conversion would be needed. I would need to look at this more closely but see [this link](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html) for more in case it helps

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you!